# Pass non static attribute to superclass in java

Tags: java, attributes, abstract

I have a problem in java. I have a superclass, which have different subclasses. Each subclass has an own cycle, that goes higher with each loop instance. I have a method, in the subclass, that has to show the cycle of each object of the subclass, the problem is, it is a non-estatic attribute so i can´t pass it through super()...
how can i do it, i am really desperate.

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public GameObject(String initial, int vida, int damage, int turn){

        this.initial = initial;
        this.vida=vida;
        this.damage=damage;
        this.turnos=turn; /*this is the fixed number where each object makes a move*/
        this.counter=0; /*i guess it starts with 0 when i create it*/
    }

    public String storeToString(){
        String p= this.initial + " [l:" + this.vida + " x:" + this.x +  " y:" + this.y + " t:" + (turnos-counter) + "] " ;
        return p;}

}
```

the problem is that i need each cycle to get higher with each loop (and when it arrive to the max turn, it becomes 0 again, but i don´t know how to bring the cycle from the subclass... ¿can someone help me please? thank you very much.

Comment: If the superclass doesn’t have the tracker and you need to count instances, you’ll have to put the counter somewhere else and pass it to each instance as you create it. So the logical place to do that is where you instantiate each instance.

Comment: Another thought is that if you have `GameObject`s and all you need to do is take turns, one after the other, is just omit the `turn` and the `counter` in the object itself, and put all objects in a `List`.  Then just iterate over the list (`for` loop) and process the objects one at a time in turn.